# Displaying a PDF on a website

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I require some assistance, I have a pdf file that is located on a ftp location.

What i want to do, is on a button click i want to retrieve the pdf file and display it on a new tab.

Please assist on how to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to consider embedding your PDF in an iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the HTML anchor tag ("a" tag). In the `href` attribute put the FTP address of the PDF file (eg. `ftp://example.com/file.pdf`). To open in a new window you should also specify a `target` attribute with the value `"_blank"`.

Example:

`<a href='ftp://example.com/file.pdf' target='_blank'>Click here to open the PDF file</a>`

Comment: This assumes the browser can handle the pdf or has a plug-in that can handle it.  Otherwise, the user may be prompted to save/download the file.

Comment: Normally if the browser can handle the pdf it may display it. Otherwise it will give the option to download to the file system.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to make a web request to download the file and then pass the download stream along to the ASP.NET response stream.  I haven't compiled or executed this code, but it might look something like this:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.yoursite.com/yourfile.pdf");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser","ftppassword");

// Get the response
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

// Send the response directly to output
Response.ContentEncoding = responseStream.CurrentEncoding;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.Write(responseStream.ReadToEnd());
Response.End();
```